# Notifying a closed app when LocalNotifications are received (iOS and Android)

Tags: xamarin.forms

- Xamarin Forms
- iOS and Android
- Shiny Framework

If an iOS or Android app is not running will the app be woken and notified when a Local Notification is received? The Local Notification will have been "sent" by the app but scheduled for a time in the future, typically the following day.

We are using Shiny Framework's Notification and want to create recurring notifications. The current implementation is implementing the `NotificationDelegate.OnReceived` method but that does not seem to get called if the app is not running

Comment: Local Notification is what you create from within the App. 
You said, you want to wake up the app using notification that you send from your backend which is Silent Notification. So You send the Silent notification then for some interval your app is allowed to do background work, that time you create your Local Notification !

Comment: I am sending a Local Notification, from the app that is scheduled for some time on the future. When that notification arrives I want the app to know

Comment: When you create notification from within your app using your code - Local Notification. 
When you send from your server or outside of your app - Push notification which you can send as Silent notification or normal push notification.
When you say you send "Local notification" I think it's a wrong. Local are local you don't send from anywhere, you create and show from within the App itself.

Comment: We are not pushing them from outside the app

Comment: So your problem is, your app will be in background/closed state and you still want to show Local notification right? but the app can not create on it's own because it wont be able to do anything in background until its wake.

Solution, You just send the Silent notification to your app from your backend, and your app will get awake then you can create the local notification and show

Comment: The Local Notification will show. That is not the problem as the OS will deal with the displaying of the Notification if we are closed. The problem is I want the app to be woken up and told the notification has arrived. We are trying to implement daily reminders using LOCAL notifications so when today's notiifcation arrives I need to wake up and schedule tomorrow's

Comment: Gotcha. 
Did you checked this one : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app?language=objc
This is for iOS.

Comment: That's just the functionality I want but the iOS or Android specific parts of the app are shielded behind a common library and so I cannot get access to those settings